# Open a Read Only file as non read only and save/overwrite

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, readonly

I have a number of word documents I am converting. Everything is going great until I get a file that is read only. In this case I get a Save As prompt.

Is there any way to open the file in read/write format? I should have admin privileges so access isn't an issue.

I'm using VB.net to open the files. More specifically

```
doc = word.Documents.Open(path, Type.Missing, False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open a read-only file you need to set that attribute to false:

```
string path = "C:\\test.txt";
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);
info.IsReadOnly = false;
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
writer.WriteLine("This is an example.");
writer.Close();
info.IsReadOnly=true;
```

This was an example but I'm sure it will work with word files.

**EDIT:**

VB.NET equivalent:

```
Dim path As String = "C:\test.txt"
Dim info As FileInfo = New FileInfo(path)
info.IsReadOnly = False
Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path)
writer.WriteLine("This is an example.")
writer.Close()
info.IsReadOnly = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you open the file, check its Attributes with a FileInfo class.

If the Attributes property contains FileAttributes.ReadOnly, change it and the file will no longer be read-only.